# Impulse response analysis

Tags: python-3.x, regression

I ran an impulse response analysis on a value weighted stock index and a few variables in python and got the following results:

[image: Impulse Response]

I am not sure how to interpret these results.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check the book **"New introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis"** by Helmut Lutkepohl, 2005, for a slightly dense theory about the method.

In the meantime, a simple way you can interpret your plots is, let's say your variables are *VW*, *SP500*, *oil*, *uts*, *prod*, *cpi*, *n3* and *usd*. They all are parts of the same system; what the impulse response analysis does is, try to assess how much one variable impacts another one independently of the other variables. Therefore, it is a pairwise shock from one variable to another. Your first plot is VW -> VW, this is pretty much an autocorrelation plot. Now, look at the other plots: apparently, *SP500* exerts a maximum impact on *VW* (you can see a peak in the blue line reaching 0.25. The y-axis is given in standard deviations and x-axis in lag-periods. So in your example, *SP500* cause a 0.25 change in *VW* at the lag of whatever is in your x-axis (I can't see from your figure). Similarly, you can see *n3* negatively impacting *VW* at a given period.

There is an interesting link that you probably know and shows an example of the application of [Python statsmodels VAR for Impulse Response analysis](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html?highlight=impulse)

I used this method to assess how one variable impact another in a plant-water-atmosphere system, there are some explanations there and also the interpretation of similar plots, take a look:
[Use of remote sensing indicators to assess effects of drought and human-induced land degradation on ecosystem health in Northeastern Brazil](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425718302050)

Good luck!